# IPSec multithreading via pcrypt worse than single thread

Tags: performance, cpu, hardware, multithreading, ipsec

According to this document:
https://www.strongswan.org/docs/Steffen_Klassert_Parallelizing_IPsec.pdf parallelizing IPSec using pcrypt kernel module will make the connection much more efficient (graphs near the end of the doc). I've tried to implement this on my own, using the instructions available here: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Pcrypt and I've successfully made IPSec use multiple threads on my machine.

The problem is that the throughput is LOWER with pcrypt enabled, meaning that the single threaded IPSec performance yields better results (with parallelizing on the throughput is around 400 Mbits/s lower than without it). What could be the issue here? My guesses:

- In the research that I linked, actually 2 physical CPUs are used in each host, whereas I have only one CPU, although with 2 cores.
- Most importantly - does the term "parallelizing" strictly involve 2+ physical CPUs or could it be used in CPUs with more than 1 core?

Comment: This question might be better suited on the strongswan mailing list.

Comment: Number of separate CPU [die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_(integrated_circuit)) doesn't usually have an impact, though it's architecture dependant. When threads compete for a resource it can reduce overall performance. Two cores is small these days.  I wonder if you're hitting memory bandwidth limit on lower performance hardware.